# Какой iOS эмулятор выбрать?

Tags: windows, ios

Подскажите, какие интрументы для разработки приложений под iOS лучше выбрать, на Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Полноценный инструмент для разработки под iOS только один - Xcode. Соответственно, нужна macOS.

А вот здесь уже на ваш выбор - новый/бу mac или виртуала с macOS, или хакинтош, или аренда удаленного mac. "Правильный" вариант конечно же mac.